# MCQ The nth derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

Tags: derivatives

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$ The nth derivative of f is equal to:

1. $\dfrac{2n}{(1-x)^{n+1}} $
2. $\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{2n}} $
3. $\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{n+1}} $

by Leibniz formula

$$ {\displaystyle \left( \dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{(n)}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{\binom {n}{k}}\ (1+x)^{(k)}\ \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)^{(n-k)}}$$

using the hint

- $\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=\dfrac{2-(1-x)}{1-x}=\dfrac2{1-x}-1$ and
- $\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{n}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}n!}{x^{n+1}}$

so

$${\displaystyle \left( \dfrac{1+x}{1-x} \right)^{(n)} = \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x}-1 \right)^{(n)}=2\dfrac{ (-1)^{n}n! }{ (1-x)^{n+1} }   }  $$ but this result isn't apear in any proposed answers

what about the method of **Lord Shark the Unknown**

tell me please this way holds for any mqc question contain find the n th derivative so it's suffice to check each answer in y case i will start with first

- let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2n}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2(n+1)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{-2n(n+1)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}\neq f_{n+1}$$
- let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{2n}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{2(n+1)}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{-2(n!)(2n)}{(1-x)^{4n}}\neq f_{n+1}$$
- let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{2(n!)(n+1)}{((1-x)^{n+1})^{2}}=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{2n+2}}\neq f_{n+1}$$

Comment: How did you narrow it down to just one of those three possibilities?

Comment: In the last step you made a mistake, you have to apply the chain rule correctly.

Answer (score 5):

$$y=\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=\dfrac{2-(1-x)}{1-x}=\dfrac2{1-x}-1$$

$$\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2(-1)}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{2(-1)(-2)}{(1-x)^3}=\dfrac{2(-1)^22!}{(1-x)^{2+1}}$$

Can you follow the pattern?

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 3):

If we let $f_n$ denote the $n$-th derivative, then $f_{n+1}=f_n'$.
That is the case only for **one** of the three possible solutions you
have there.

Comment: - let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2n}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2(n+1)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{-2n(n+1)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}\neq f_{n+1}$$
 - let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{2n}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{2(n+1)}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{-2(n!)(2n)}{(1-x)^{4n}}\neq f_{n+1}$$
 - let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2(n!)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ then $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$ do i have $f'_{n}=f_{n+1}$  let calculate $$ f'_n=\dfrac{2(n!)(n+1)}{((1-x)^{n+1})^{2}}=\dfrac{2((n+1)!)}{(1-x)^{2n+2}}\neq f_{n+1}$$

Comment: @Cyro The first and third examples differ only by a scalar multiple, yet your derivatives do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Leibniz's formula (not that it's easier than without it); just consider that
$$
(1+x)^{(k)}=
\begin{cases}
1+x & k=0 \\
1 & k=1 \\
0 & k>1
\end{cases}
$$
so the formula gives
$$
\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\!(n)}=
(1+x)\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\!(n)}+
n\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\!(n-1)}
$$
Now make a conjecture about
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\!(n)}
$$

Comment: $$\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)^{n}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: That derivative is incorrect, you are missing another $(-1)^n$

Comment: @Cyro Try the first and second derivatives. You'll see that there is no minus sign in front.